# Using Argument from Function to Re-Direct Visitor (WordPress)

Tags: php, redirect

After googling around and reading, I found the code below. Problem is, it's been a few weeks and I've lost the original post.

I have now done my best in understanding how to create a function hooked into `template_redirect` so that I can re-direct visitors based on the country they are from.

I understand that this is not bullet-proof and what not, but it's the best working solution I found that does not require a paid plugin.

**This is the IP and Country function:**

```
function visitor_ip_and_country() {

    $client = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $country = "Unknown";

    if ( filter_var( $client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP ) ) {
        $ip = $client;
    }

    elseif ( filter_var( $forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP ) ) {
        $ip = $forward;
    } else {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
    $ip_data_in = curl_exec( $ch )
    curl_close( $ch );

    $ip_data = json_decode( $ip_data_in, true );
    $ip_data = str_replace( '&quot;', '"', $ip_data );

    if ( $ip_data && $ip_data['geoplugin_countryName'] != null ) {
        $country = $ip_data['geoplugin_countryName'];
    }

    return 'IP-address: '.$ip.' | Country: '.$country;
}
```

I have then tried to create a function that re-directs users, but I keep getting an "undefined variable" error.

**Here is that code:**

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canadians' );
function redirect_canadians() {
    
    $redirect = '';
    
    $vc = visitor_ip_and_country($country);

        if ($vc == 'Canada') {
        
            $redirect = 'https://example.com';
            
            wp_redirect($redirect);
            
            die();
    }
}
```

**It refers to this line:**

```
$vc = visitor_ip_and_country($country);
```

I don't know how to get the re-direct function to check the argument from the `visitor_ip_and_country()` function.

I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the variable `$sountry` - and this is because of something called variable scope - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php - the variable is only available within the function, as you do not "export" it or make it globally available - here is an update to your functions to show how this might work:

```php
function visitor_ip_and_country() {

    $client = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $country = "Unknown";

    if ( filter_var( $client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP ) ) {
        $ip = $client;
    }

    elseif ( filter_var( $forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP ) ) {
        $ip = $forward;
    } else {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
    $ip_data_in = curl_exec( $ch )
    curl_close( $ch );

    $ip_data = json_decode( $ip_data_in, true );
    $ip_data = str_replace( '&quot;', '"', $ip_data );

    if ( $ip_data && $ip_data['geoplugin_countryName'] != null ) {
        $country = $ip_data['geoplugin_countryName'];
    }

    return array( 
        'ip'       => $ip, 
        'country'  = >$country
        // note, you could add additional keys to this array
    );
}


add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canadians' );
function redirect_canadians() {

    // call your function to get an array with IP and country values ##
    $array = visitor_ip_and_country();
    
    $redirect = '';
    
    $vc = $array['country'];

        if ($vc == 'Canada') {
        
            $redirect = 'https://example.com';
            
            wp_redirect($redirect);
            
            die();
    }
}
```

This is a simple solution, get it working, then refine it more.

Comment: It is very strict now, so is less reliable - perhaps "Canada" is actually "canada" etc - so you might need to try other matching methods, such as strpos

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I just noticed your last update. All working as intended now. Again, thank you and thanks for explaining.